# dplyr::mutate on objects with multiple classes

Tags: r, dplyr, coercion

I have the following code:

```
x <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 1:10)
class(x) <- c("data.frame", "somthingelse")
x %>% dplyr::mutate(c = a)
```

and I get the following error:

```
Error: `x` must be a vector, not a <data.frame/soethingelse> object.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I usually assume, that the object can be function as a `data.frame` OR as `something else`, so I would expect this to work?

Do I understand something wrong here?

======

Edit : I am talking about S3 classes. There might be differences for different class models.

Comment: Class inheritance issue. Your code means `x` is of sub-class `"data.frame"` whose parent class is `"somethingelse"`. Apparently, this does not work since `"somethingelse"` is not a defined class in R. If you change the order (`class(x) <- c("somthingelse", "data.frame")`, making `"somethingelse"` a sub-class of `"data.frame"`), then it should work.

Comment: OK - but if I define a function `as.data.frame.somethingelse <- function(x, ...) {class(x) <- "data.frame"}` and put it into the package, `as.data.frame(x)` assumes that x is a data frame and does not call that function.

Comment: Did you [`setClass`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/methods/versions/3.6.2/topics/setClass) in your package? I cannot reproduce your error since after I `setClass` and define `"somethingelse"` properly, the function is called as expected. @Rainer

Comment: @ekoam I am using S3 classes, and, as far as I know, these do not require the use of `setClass()` as they are defined by the class attribute - or am I missing something here? Maybe S4 classes would have been safer, but in my case they would have been an overkill.

Comment: Please see my addition to the question for clarification.

Comment: Ok, I tried again with no `setClass` at all and my code like this works perfectly fine. `as.data.frame.somethingelse <- function(x, ...) {x$a = "hello"; class(x) <- "data.frame"; x}; x <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 1:10); class(x) <- c("somethingelse", "data.frame"); as.data.frame(x)`. Now I think it could be just due to typos. I spotted two different spellings in your post: 1) class(x) <- c("data.frame", "**som**thingelse") 2) ... data.frame/ **soe**thingelse ... Both are wrong.